# ¿Como puedo interpretar esta consulta mysql en el model de codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

```
select nombre,nombre_comando,valor 
from servidor S, configuracion C, configuracionservidor F 
where F.id_servidor = S.id 
and F.id_configuracion=C.id
```

Esta consulta me funciona en `Mysql` pero al momento de  escribirla en el **model** de `codeigniter`  no logro que me muestre los resultados de la consulta en la vista

Esta función mostrara la información de la tabla [configuracionservidor]

```
    public function mostrarSerconf(){
        $q= $this->db->get("select nombre,nombre_comando,valor from servidor,configuracion,configuracionservidor where configuracionservidor.id_servidor=servidor.id and configuracionservidor.id_configuracion=configuracion.id");

        if($q->num_rows()>0){
            return $q;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Este es mi controlador

```
public function  servConf(){
   $datos = array('mostrar2'=>  $this->modelo_principal->mostrarSerconf());
   $this->load->view('servConf',$datos);
}
```

Esto es lo que tengo en mi vista

```
 <?php
        if ($mostrar2 == null) {
          echo 
          "<h3>"."SIN INFORMACÓN PARA MOSTRAR"."</h3>";
        }else{
            foreach ($mostrar2->result() as $fila) {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>"."<b>".$fila->id."</b>"."</td>";
              echo "<td>"."<center>".$fila->id_servidor."</center>"."</td>";
              echo "<td>"."<center>".$fila->id_configuracion."</center>"."</td>";
              echo "<td>".$fila->valor."</td>";
              echo "<td>"."<a href=".base_url()."principal/editarServi/".$fila->id.'>Editar</a></td>';
              echo "<td>"."<a href=".base_url()."principal/eliminarServi/".$fila->id.'>Eliminar</a></td>';
               echo "</tr>";
            }
          }
      ?>
```

Comment: Añade la forma en que estás trabajando esa consulta en `PHP` para poder ayudarte

Comment: listo agregue mas información espero puedan apoyarme gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La consulta sería así:

```
$this->db->select('nombre,nombre_comando,valor');
$this->db->from('servidor S, configuracion C, configuracionservidor F');
$this->db->where('F.id_servidor = S.id and F.id_configuracion=C.id');

$q = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

Para codeigniter se usa el patrón de base de datos llamado active record, con el que se realizarán todas las consultas sql. El cual te facilita un poco la vida realizando consultas más seguras y sirve para cualquier adaptador de base de datos.

En la primera línea se pondrían los campos que quieres que aparezcan en la consulta (select).
En el from (segunda línea), se especifíca las tablas de la consulta.
En la 3 línea, where, se indica la condición. 
Con result_array() devuelve un array de todos los registros de la consulta.

En tu caso sería así:

```
public function mostrarSerconf(){
        $this->db->select('nombre,nombre_comando,valor');
        $this->db->from('servidor S, configuracion C, configuracionservidor F');
        $this->db->where('F.id_servidor = S.id and F.id_configuracion=C.id');

        $q = $this->db->get();

        if($q->num_rows()>0){            
            return $q->result_array();
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Y en la plantilla habría que cambiar el foreach:

```
 foreach ($mostrar2 as $fila) {
```

Comment: recuerda que no es solo poner el código y ya, debes explicarla

Comment: En la plantilla el "foreach ($mostrar2->result() as $fila) {" se transforma en "foreach ($mostrar2 as $fila) {"

Comment: muchas gracias ,

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la impresión - *sin saber mucho de `CI` y sólo viendo la documentación* -, que estas confundiendo las formas en las que se manejan las consultas con este Framework.

> **$this->db->get()** devuelve todos los resultados de una tabla, lo que
>   equivale a "Ejecutar" la consulta cuando ya la construiste

Por lo que tu consulta debería tener esta estructura

```
$this->db->select('t1.col, t2.col');
$this->db->from('tabla1 AS t1, tabla2 AS t2');

$where = array('t1.col ' => $filtro , 't1.otraCol' => $otroFiltro);
$this->db->where($where);

$query = $this->db->get();
```

Te dejo la **[documentación](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html)** para que la consultes :)